# Where to save single time use data for vuejs in webpack setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

This is the current setup that I have with my vuejs & webpack.

I have a Vue file: `gallery.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="gallery">
        <figure style="background-color:#1a1c23;">
            <img 
                src="./assets/img/someimage1.png" 
                alt="Alt text for image 1" 
                title="title text for image 1"
                data-src="./assets/link-additional-image1.png"
                data-color="#1a1c23">
        </figure>
        <figure style......
        </figure>
        // A large number of these figure elements
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import GalleryItem from './component/galleryItem.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Gallery',
    components: {
        GalleryItem
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the component file `galleryItem.vue`

```
<template>
    <figure v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:backgroundColor}">
    <img 
        v-bind:src="src" 
        v-bind:alt="alt" 
        v-bind:title="title"
        v-bind:data-src="dataSrc"
        v-bind:data-color="dataColor">
    </figure>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'GalleryItem',
    props: {
        backgroundColor: String,
        src: String,
        alt: String,
        title: String,
        dataSrc: String,
        dataColor: String
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want to do instead is have an array of object, something like below, and recursively create galleryItem components in gallery component using that array.

How can I achieve this? I don't know where to save the array and how to pass it to the vue components, I was thinking to have the array in a seprate javascript file.

Or if this is a wrong approach ?

```
var a = [
{
    backgroundColor: "#480572",
    src: "./assets/img/someimage1.png",
    alt: "Alt text for image 1",
    title: "title text for image 1",
    dataSrc: "./assets/link-additional-image1.png",
    dataColor: "#ebebf7"
},
{
    backgroundColor: "#2A3132",
    src: "./assets/img/someimage2.png",
    alt: "Alt text for image 2",
    title: "title text for image 1",
    dataSrc: "./assets/link-additional-image2.png",
    dataColor: "#FFFFFF"
},
....
// A large number of these items
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save it to a separate js file and import from there.

```
//../assets/gallery.js or where ever you want to save the file

export const gallery = [
{
    backgroundColor: "#480572",
    src: "./assets/img/someimage1.png",
    alt: "Alt text for image 1",
    title: "title text for image 1",
    dataSrc: "./assets/link-additional-image1.png",
    dataColor: "#ebebf7"
},
{
    backgroundColor: "#2A3132",
    src: "./assets/img/someimage2.png",
    alt: "Alt text for image 2",
    title: "title text for image 1",
    dataSrc: "./assets/link-additional-image2.png",
    dataColor: "#FFFFFF"
},
....
// A large number of these items
]
```

In gallery component

```
<script>
import GalleryItem from './component/galleryItem.vue'
import { gallery } from '../assets/gallery.js'

export default {
    name: 'Gallery',
    data() {
       return {
          gallery
       }
    },
    components: {
        GalleryItem
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: But, doesn't that breaks the webpack flow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.